AutoDelegation not triggered
I am trying to get AutoDelegate to work (or any slot-filling method, because nothing seems to work for me). Strangely I have a request where it works perfectly, but anything I create new from scratch fails, even the most basic example.
Essentially, the slot-delegation is NEVER triggered at all, it practically goes straight to the "COMPLETED" stage, no matter if slots are required, require confirmation, if the whole request requires confirmation - everything seems to be ignored. I am loosing my mind if I hear or read one more time that "the intent won't be even hit, until all slots are filled".
It goes like this:

Trigger intent with utterance without slot
Hit InProgressSlotIntentHandler with state STARTED
return addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
State suddenly COMPLETED without filling any slots
Hits SlotIntentHandler and code fails because slots are not filled

The logged request-data also clearly shows that no slot was confirmed, but that it goes straight into COMPLETED
{
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.786ea058-6258-4e8e-8eac-a777f561b3a6",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2024-09-20T09:35:22Z",
    "intent": {
        "name": "SlotIntent",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "firstName": {
                "name": "firstName",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            },
            "testSlot": {
                "name": "testSlot",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
            }
        }
    },
    "dialogState": "COMPLETED"
}

Even when using working templates (e.g. https://github.com/dabblelab/12-alexa-dialog-delegate-example-skill from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHtK_BbYb0) copied 1:1 it does not want to work.
Here is the extract from my most basic model (simplified)
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "SlotIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "testSlot",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                            "samples": [
                                "give me a fact about {testSlot}",
                                "tell me some facts about {testSlot}",
                                "{testSlot}"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "tell me",
                        "tell me about {testSlot}"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "dialog": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "SlotIntent",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "prompts": {},
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "testSlot",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE",
                            "confirmationRequired": false,
                            "elicitationRequired": true,
                            "prompts": {
                                "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.251925459829.983270759031"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
        },
        "prompts": [
            {
                "id": "Elicit.Slot.251925459829.983270759031",
                "variations": [
                    {
                        "type": "PlainText",
                        "value": "Give me a date."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

And the 2 intents for handling the delegation and final output
const InProgressSlotIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      request.intent.name === 'SlotIntent' &&
      request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SlotIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'SlotIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;

    let speechText = `Here's is your slot - ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.testSlot}`;
    
    return responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

In the Utterance Profiler it works correctly, but once I deploy and run (on device, in the app, or in the simulator), it straight returns me "Here is your slot - undefined"
Is this a current hiccup at Alexa, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong, because I can not see it (especially because I have a skill where the delegation works in another intent, but ANYTHING new just does not..)

I also tried adding slot-confirmation, intent-confirmation - AutoDelegation is active globally for all intents (tho that should not make any difference, because it is also set on this intent specifically). I just don't get Alexa to interact with the slots at all.

I do not really have an answer, but I created a NEW HelloWorld skill from scratch and copied the interaction JSON-model 1:1 in there - and with the new skill the AutoDelegation works (though it somehow breaks quite easily and quits with mysterious "Can't find skill bundle metadata for en_US" errors if I modify things - but at least it seems like even then it TRIES to do AutoDelegation, it just gets confused itself where to find the prompt-resources??)
So I guess my only path forward is to scrap the existing skill and copy all data to a new one?
Luckily the skill is still in development, but that cannot be a solution. I still do not know why this is happening in the first place :-/
